Creates a list containing the worksheets and the formulas in them
I have debugged and developed a sourced macro embedded in the comments within the macro below.
This macro creates a list all formulas in a workbook. A new worksheet is added and the formulas, including the sheet name and cell address, are listed in Columns A, B and C.
The macro now works correctly.
I would like help in developing a macro so that the names of worksheets that do not contain formulas also appear in the list, leaving the cell address and corresponding formulas blank.
Here is an explanation
The workbook contains 4 sheets named: 1 to 4. The first sheet (Named 1) does not contain formulas. The rest of the worksheets (Named 2, 3, 4) contain formulas.
The result of executing the macro in its current form will be as follows:
Sheet Name  Cell Address    Formula
2   A1  2+1
3   A3  SUM(A1:A2)
3   B3  A3+1
4   F4  D4-C9
4   B9  SUM(B7:B8)
4   C9  SUM(C7:C8)

The result I want to get is:
Sheet Name  Cell Address    Formula
1       
2   A1  2+1
3   A3  SUM(A1:A2)
3   B3  A3+1
4   F4  D4-C9
4   B9  SUM(B7:B8)
4   C9  SUM(C7:C8)

Here is the code of the macro in its current form:
Sub ListAllFormulas()
'Original Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=409
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shtName
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim newRng As Range
    Dim c As Range
     
ReTry:
    shtName = Application.InputBox("Choose a name for the new sheet to list all formulas.", "New Sheet Name") 'the user decides the new sheet name
    If shtName = False Then Exit Sub 'exit if user clicks Cancel
     
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Sheets(shtName) 'check if the sheet exists
    If Not sht Is Nothing Then 'if so, send message and return to input box
        MsgBox "This sheet already exists"
        Err.Clear 'clear error
        Set sht = Nothing 'reset sht for next test
        GoTo ReTry 'loop to input box
    End If
     
    Worksheets.Add.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'adds a new sheet at the end
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet 'the new sheet is automatically the activesheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Sheet Name" 'puts a heading in cell A1
        .Range("B1").Value = "Cell Address" 'puts a heading in cell B1
        .Range("C1").Value = "Formula" 'puts a heading in cell C1
        .Name = shtName 'names the new sheet from InputBox
    End With
     
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through the sheets in the workbook
        If sht.Name <> shtName Then 'exclude the sheet just created
            Set myRng = sht.UsedRange 'limit the search to the UsedRange
            If Not myRng.HasFormula Then GoTo 50 'Skip the worksheet if it does not contain formulas.
            On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no formulas
            Set newRng = myRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 'use SpecialCells to reduce looping further
            For Each c In newRng 'loop through the SpecialCells only
                
                Sheets(shtName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sht.Name
                 'places the sheet name containing the formula in column A
                Sheets(shtName).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c.Address, "$", "")
                 'places the cell address, minus the "$" signs, containing the formula in column B
                 Sheets(shtName).Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Mid(c.Formula, 2, (Len(c.Formula)))
                 'places the formula minus the '=' sign in column C
50:
    Next c
        End If
    Next sht
    Sheets(shtName).Activate 'make the new sheet the activesheet
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:C").AutoFit 'autofit the data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

The current macro only shows a list of worksheets that contain formulas. What I want is a development that shows all the worksheets.

Just edit the If Not myRng.HasFormula Then GoTo 50 to : IF myRng.HasFormula THEN current_code_to_add_formula_specs ELSE code_to_add_just_sheetname

You could do this by changing your logic a bit, it might also be an idea to add some variables that reference the destination sheet/range.
Option Explicit

Sub ListAllFormulas()
'Original Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=409
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim shtNew As Worksheet
Dim myRng As Range
Dim newRng As Range
Dim rngDst As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim shtName As String

ReTry:
    shtName = Application.InputBox("Choose a name for the new sheet to list all formulas.", "New Sheet Name") 'the user decides the new sheet name
    If shtName = "False" Then Exit Sub 'exit if user clicks Cancel
     
    On Error Resume Next
    Set shtNew = Sheets(shtName) 'check if the sheet exists
    If Not shtNew Is Nothing Then 'if so, send message and return to input box
        MsgBox "This sheet already exists"
        Err.Clear 'clear error
        Set shtNew = Nothing 'reset sht for next test
        GoTo ReTry 'loop to input box
    End If
     
    Worksheets.Add.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'adds a new sheet at the end
    Set shtNew = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With shtNew 'the new sheet is automatically the activesheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Sheet Name" 'puts a heading in cell A1
        .Range("B1").Value = "Cell Address" 'puts a heading in cell B1
        .Range("C1").Value = "Formula" 'puts a heading in cell C1
        .Name = shtName 'names the new sheet from InputBox
        Set rngDst = .Range("A2")
    End With
     
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through the sheets in the workbook
        If sht.Name <> shtNew.Name Then 'exclude the sheet just created
            Set myRng = sht.UsedRange 'limit the search to the UsedRange
            If myRng.HasFormula Then   'Skip the worksheet if it does not contain formulas.
                On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no formulas
                Set newRng = myRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 'use SpecialCells to reduce looping further
                For Each c In newRng 'loop through the SpecialCells only
                
                    rngDst.Value = sht.Name
                    'places the sheet name containing the formula in column A
                    rngDst.Offset(, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c.Address, "$", "")
                    'places the cell address, minus the "$" signs, containing the formula in column B
                    rngDst.Offset(, 1).Value = Mid(c.Formula, 2, (Len(c.Formula)))
                    'places the formula minus the '=' sign in column C
                    Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
                Next c
            Else
                rngDst = sht.Name
                Set rngDst = rngDst.Offset(1)
            End If
        End If
        
    Next sht
    
    With shtNew
        .Columns("A:C").AutoFit 'autofit the data
        Application.Goto .Range("A1"), True
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub



List Formulas
Usage
Sub RunListFormulas()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    ListFormulas wb, True, True, True
End Sub

The Method
Sub ListFormulas( _
        wb As Workbook, _
        Optional ExcludeEqualSign As Boolean = False, _
        Optional IncludeNoFormulaWorksheets As Boolean = False, _
        Optional IncludeCharts As Boolean = False, _
        Optional MaxCellsPerSheet As Long = 1000)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "List Formulas"
    
    ' Input Box:
    Const IB_PROMPT As String _
        = "Choose a name for the new sheet to list all formulas."
    Const SHEET_RENAME_QUESTION As String = "Do you want to try again?"
    Const SHEET_DOESNT_EXIST_QUESTION As String = "Do you want to try again?"
    ' Formula Sheet:
    Dim Titles() As Variant:
    Titles = VBA.Array("Sheet Name", "Cell Address", "Formula")
    Const FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS As String = "A1:C1"
    Const TOO_MANY_CELLS As String = "Too many cells!"
    Const NO_FORMULA As String = "No formula!"
    Const IS_A_CHART As String = "Chart!"
     
    Dim fsh As Object, fws As Worksheet, FormulasSheetName As Variant
    Dim Answer As Long, WasSheetAdded As Boolean
    
    Do
        
        FormulasSheetName _
            = Application.InputBox(IB_PROMPT, PROC_TITLE, , , , , , 2)
        If FormulasSheetName = False Then Exit Sub ' canceled by user
        
        On Error Resume Next
            Set fsh = wb.Sheets(FormulasSheetName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If fsh Is Nothing Then
            If Not WasSheetAdded Then
                Set fws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
                WasSheetAdded = True
            End If
            On Error Resume Next
                fws.Name = FormulasSheetName
            On Error GoTo 0
            If fws.Name = FormulasSheetName Then Exit Do ' valid name :-)
            Answer = MsgBox("Could not rename to """ & FormulasSheetName _
                & """!" & vbLf & SHEET_RENAME_QUESTION, _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_TITLE)
            If Answer = vbNo Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                    fws.Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else
            Answer = MsgBox("A sheet named """ & fsh.Name _
                & """ already exists!" & vbLf & SHEET_DOESNT_EXIST_QUESTION, _
                vbQuestion + vbYesNo, PROC_TITLE)
            If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub
            Set fsh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    
    Loop
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim frrg As Range: Set frrg = fws.Range(FIRST_ROW_ADDRESS)
    frrg.Value = Titles
    Set frrg = frrg.Offset(1)
    
    Dim ssh As Object, srg As Range, scell As Range, sCellsCount As Double
    Dim sName As String, sFormula As String
    Dim fData As Variant, fr As Long
    
    For Each ssh In wb.Sheets
        sName = ssh.Name
        If TypeOf ssh Is Worksheet Then
            If sName <> FormulasSheetName Then
                On Error Resume Next
                    Set srg = ssh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                On Error GoTo 0
                If srg Is Nothing Then
                    If IncludeNoFormulaWorksheets Then
                        frrg.Cells(1).Value = sName
                        frrg.Cells(3).Value = NO_FORMULA
                        Set frrg = frrg.Offset(1)
                    End If
                Else
                    sCellsCount = srg.Cells.CountLarge
                    If sCellsCount <= MaxCellsPerSheet Then
                        ReDim fData(1 To sCellsCount, 1 To 3)
                        fr = 0
                        For Each scell In srg.Cells
                            fr = fr + 1
                            fData(fr, 1) = sName
                            fData(fr, 2) = scell.Address(0, 0)
                            sFormula = scell.Formula
                            If ExcludeEqualSign Then
                                sFormula = Right(sFormula, Len(sFormula) - 1)
                            End If
                            fData(fr, 3) = sFormula
                        Next scell
                        frrg.Resize(sCellsCount).Value = fData
                        Set frrg = frrg.Offset(sCellsCount)
                    Else
                        frrg.Cells(1).Value = sName
                        frrg.Cells(3).Value = TOO_MANY_CELLS
                        Set frrg = frrg.Offset(1)
                    End If
                    Set srg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
                End If
            End If
        ElseIf TypeOf ssh Is Chart Then
            If IncludeCharts Then
                frrg.Cells(1).Value = sName
                frrg.Cells(3).Value = IS_A_CHART
                Set frrg = frrg.Offset(1)
            End If
        'Else ' neither worksheet nor chart: e.g. dialog
        End If
    Next ssh
    
    frrg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    fws.Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub


vbasic2008
I tried the code you provided, and it worked properly.
your code includes a useful clarification indicating that there are no formulas in the worksheets to which this applies.
Thank you very much.

Added a small code after myRng is set in your code
If Not myRng.HasFormula Then
    Sheets(shtName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sht.Name
    Sheets(shtName).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "_"
    Sheets(shtName).Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "_"
    GoTo 50 'Skip the worksheet if it does not contain formulas.
End If

Image of the sheets
Sheet Named 1: Sheet without formula

Sheet Named 2: with formulas

Sub ListAllFormulas()
'Original Source: http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=409
Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim shtName
    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim newRng As Range
    Dim c As Range
     
ReTry:
    shtName = Application.InputBox("Choose a name for the new sheet to list all formulas.", "New Sheet Name") 'the user decides the new sheet name
    If shtName = False Then Exit Sub 'exit if user clicks Cancel
     
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Sheets(shtName) 'check if the sheet exists
    If Not sht Is Nothing Then 'if so, send message and return to input box
        MsgBox "This sheet already exists"
        Err.Clear 'clear error
        Set sht = Nothing 'reset sht for next test
        GoTo ReTry 'loop to input box
    End If
     
    Worksheets.Add.Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count) 'adds a new sheet at the end
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ActiveSheet 'the new sheet is automatically the activesheet
        .Range("A1").Value = "Sheet Name" 'puts a heading in cell A1
        .Range("B1").Value = "Cell Address" 'puts a heading in cell B1
        .Range("C1").Value = "Formula" 'puts a heading in cell C1
        .Name = shtName 'names the new sheet from InputBox
    End With
        
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'loop through the sheets in the workbook
        If sht.Name <> shtName Then 'exclude the sheet just created
            Set myRng = sht.UsedRange 'limit the search to the UsedRange
            If Not myRng.HasFormula Then
                Sheets(shtName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sht.Name
                Sheets(shtName).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "_"
                Sheets(shtName).Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "_"
                GoTo 50 'Skip the worksheet if it does not contain formulas.
            End If
            
            On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no formulas
            Set newRng = myRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) 'use SpecialCells to reduce looping further
            For Each c In newRng 'loop through the SpecialCells only
                    
                Sheets(shtName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = sht.Name
                 'places the sheet name containing the formula in column A
                Sheets(shtName).Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(c.Address, "$", "")
                 'places the cell address, minus the "$" signs, containing the formula in column B
                 Sheets(shtName).Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Mid(c.Formula, 2, (Len(c.Formula)))
                 'places the formula minus the '=' sign in column C
50:
    Next c
        End If
    Next sht
    Sheets(shtName).Activate 'make the new sheet the activesheet
    ActiveSheet.Columns("A:C").AutoFit 'autofit the data
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub

Output sheet


The code received from Mr. Senthil P Nathan was applied and worked exactly as requested. So my question has been answered. Just do not forget to add the following line at the beginning of the Nathan’s code:
Dim boolSheetHasFormula As Boolean

@MarwanBarakat, Actually I forgot to remove the line               boolSheetHasFormula = True ' Added Newly on 11 May 2024. It was written earlier then changed it. So you can remove that line as it is not needed. I have updated the answer too.
